# First condition of Alternating Series Test, for the sequence $(-1)^n\cdot \ln(n)/n^{1/2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

does not satisfy the first condition of the Alternating Series Test:

$b_{n+1}$ less than or equal to $b_n$, for all $n$ (for example $n=2$),

and yet still converges by the Alternating Series Test.

I thought about this myself and I thought the reason was, because for large enough n the sequence is decreasing and because a finite number of terms does not affect the convergence/divergence of series, it follows that the series starting from $n=1$ also converges.

Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. If the terms are eventually decreasing then the tail of the series satisfies the alternating series test, and only the tail matters for convergence.